# Programmatic option to save data for restore later

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I manage an ecommerce site that is built on ASP.NET with NHibernate and Castle ActiveRecord using SQL Server 2008R2 with about 100k products. Products have a normal price and a sale price. the client wants to be able to run a sale (like Black Friday) with certain sale prices (percent off normal price) for a couple days, then return the products' sale prices to what they were before the super sale. only about 2500 products are involved in the super sale.

is there a programmatic option for saving the pre-super-sale prices to be able to restore them after the super-sale? is there such a thing as a project that will save data or state for some period of time and then restore? I only want to restore the sale prices.

I could manually export a view of the table from SSMS to an INSERT script, but the client wouldn't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include a (special) discount column and calculate it into the prices, then when there is a special day just update the discount, and reset it to 0 when done.